# Mails not being received. status=deferred (lost connection with 127.0.0.1

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot, spamassassin

I have a MiaB box with about 30 email boxes. This errror pops up in /var/log/mail.err but with no other information.

```
WARNING! Error in process_request eval block: /usr/sbin/spampd: write error saving data
```

How can I trace it and fix it ? I believe people are not receiving their emails when this happens.

This is when a user sends a message with an attachment to another mailbox on the same server:

```
Jun 15 14:52:45 ubuntu opendkim[23335]: domain.com: key data is not secure: /home/user-data is writeable and owned by uid 1001 which is not the executing uid (111) or the superuser
Jun 15 14:52:48 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[10579]: E763B5EFA4: from=jason@domain.com, size=3804954, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 15 14:52:48 ubuntu dovecot: lmtp(17671): Connect from 127.0.0.1
Jun 15 14:52:48 ubuntu dovecot: lmtp(17671): Disconnect from 127.0.0.1: Connection closed (in DATA)
Jun 15 14:52:48 ubuntu spampd[17504]: WARNING!! Error in process_request eval block: /usr/sbin/spampd: write error saving data
Jun 15 14:52:48 ubuntu postfix/lmtp[17595]: E763B5EFA4: to=sylvia@domain.com, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10025, delay=14, delays=13/0/0.01/0.2, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] while sending end of data -- message may be sent more than once)
Jun 15 14:52:50 ubuntu postfix/submission/smtpd[17665]: disconnect from unknown[135.0.8.211]
Jun 15 14:53:27 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[17685]: warning: hostname nsg-static-162.165.72.182.airtel.in does not resolve to address 182.72.165.162: Name or service not known
Jun 15 14:53:27 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[17685]: connect from unknown[182.72.165.162]
```

Any ideas what's happening here ?

Comment: Seems the issue is with all emails that have attachments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling ipv6 on centos 6.5 seems to have removed this issues.

Comment: You can (should) accept your own answer, too. Click on the pipe icon on the left.

Comment: @peterh I will but I have to wait 2 more hours (out of 48) before I can do it.

Comment: O.k.! All right.